# How to properly escape raw SQL query (plainto_tsquery) in Postgres / node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, security, sql-injection

I'm writing a raw SQL query to implement Postgres full text search in my node backend.  I've looked through the [official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-controls.html), which state:

> plainto_tsquery transforms unformatted text querytext to tsquery. The text is parsed and normalized much as for to_tsvector, then the & (AND) Boolean operator is inserted between surviving words.

but I'm not familiar enough with all the different SQL injection techniques to know for certain whether the following will be properly escaped:

```
'SELECT * FROM "Products" WHERE "catalog_ts_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery(\'english\', ' + search_term + ')'
```

The user will be able to enter whatever `search_term` they want via the URI.

Do I need to do further escaping/manipulation, or is this functionality fully baked into `plainto_tsquery()` and other Postgres safeguards?

**Edit**

As a side note, I plan to strip out most non-alphanumeric characters (including parentheses) with `.replace(/[^\w-_ .\&]|\(\)/g, ' ')`; that should go a long way, but I'm still curious if this is even necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely you're using [`pg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) module as PostgreSQL client for `node.js`. In this case you don't need to worry about sql injection, `pg` prevents it for you. Just not use string concatination to create query, use **parameterized queries** (or [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)):

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM "Products" WHERE "catalog_ts_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery(\'english\', $1)';
var params = [search_term];

client.query(sql, params, function(err, result) {
    // handle error and result here
});
```

Also look at [Prepared Statment](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements) part of `pg` wiki and PostgreSQL [PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html) statement.

**UPD** What about `sequelize` - it uses `pg` module by default, but you can specify you preferable pg client in `dialectModulePath` config parameter (see [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v2.0.5/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js#L14)). Also you can use parameterized queries in `sequelize` too. Even better - you can use named parameters. So you code will be:

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM "Products" WHERE "catalog_ts_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery(\'english\', :search_term)';
var params = { search_term: search_term }

sequelize.query(sql, Product, null, params).then(function(products) {
    // handle your products here
})
```

Where `Product` is your sequelize product model.

Comment: I'm not using `pg` directly; using `sequelize` instead.  It does look like they have a way to escape values as well: `sequelize.getQueryInterface().escape(search_term)`.  If you can incorporate this into your answer, I'm happy to mark it as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Note that the format (params as 4th option to `sequelize.query`) has recently been deprecated: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/changelog.md#backwards-compatibility-changes

Comment: See here for new format with `options.replacements`: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/#replacements